# Why is Lax's statement of the minimax principle stated only for real vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reading Peter Lax's *Linear Algebra*.  On page 116 he states the minimax principle as follows: for a real symmetric operator $H$ on an $n$-dimensional real vector space,  suppose we label the eigenvalues in ascending order: $\lambda_1, \dotsc , \lambda_n$ (perhaps with repetition). Then  $$\lambda_k = \min_{\dim{S}=k}\max_{x\in S, x\neq 0}\frac{\langle Hx, x\rangle}{\langle x,x \rangle}.$$The proof he offers seems to hold for Hermitian operators on finite-dimensional complex spaces as well, and I'm wondering why he restricts to the real case. I note that on Wikipedia the theorem is stated only for real spaces as well, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant_minimax_principle), though in a similar article it is stated for complex spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem). Why restrict to the real case?

One answer might be that he prefers to focus on the real case for some reason, but on pages 113-115 he has done all the hard work to prove the theorem, and there he has explicitly considered the complex case.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but yes, the minimax principle holds for Hermitian matrices as well.